# Javascript snippet not working (missing lib?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I upgraded my Bootply.com account to download 1 snippet which is not working properly. What am I missing here [the original Bootply.com snippet](http://www.bootply.com/rqIYSDbuZg)?!

This is what my index.html looks when I run it in Chrome: [Imgur link.](http://i.imgur.com/QGVBoY5.png)

These are the includes from the index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootstrap3 Wizard w/ FuelUX</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
```

Footer:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change urls starting with `//` to `https://<url>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootstrap3 Wizard w/ FuelUX</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Footer:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

The reason is that you are opening the html file locally. Note that in the address bar, the protocol is `file://`. When you run it on a web server, however, it would work because the protocol is either `http://` or `https://`.

**Update:**

Discussion moved to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146696/bootply-com-js-snippets-missing-libs-when-downloaded/30147190#30147190).

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation ... I was just about to ask.

Comment: It is still not working, am I missing some lib like fuelux? Please, check the http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/eJLWIgwTw2

Comment: Follow here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146696/bootply-com-js-snippets-missing-libs-when-downloaded