# Bootply.com js snippets missing libs when downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is it when I download a Bootply js snippet like http://www.bootply.com/rqIYSDbuZg# is just wont look like the "visual" from  Bootply. What libs am I missing (Fuelux etc.)? It looks like this on my server: [http://imgur.com/DnFqZRB](https://imgur.com/DnFqZRB). What steps can I take to fix this?

I already applied [Javascript snippet not working (missing lib?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145627/javascript-snippet-not-working-missing-lib)

I even upgraded my Bootply account to download the snippet. Take a look https://mega.co.nz/#!BJQBmQ7a!kxGiQBbIp9AmZdTfAVsGnME5f2UWHsOD_-WtZE_cPDU

Comment: Hi @whatever1 if the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the package is missing the [Fuel UX](http://getfuelux.com/) plugin.

Adding the line below line can solve the CSS problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.6.3/css/fuelux.min.css">
```

but the buttons still don't work. Adding this to the scripts section causes unexpected behaviours:

```
<script src="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.6.3/js/fuelux.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of debugging it manually, I took the working example from the website and packaged it into [this file](https://mega.co.nz/#!w1wEFI4a!-j9kW9OUf7BTEKQ1f2-qN4wRwhBSv91CYtxRhW2nEus).

Comment: Can you define a process, how to get Bootply snippets working?

Comment: What I did is I went to http://www.bootply.com/render/rqIYSDbuZg in chrome and **File-Save Page As**. Then I formatted the HTML and took out unnecessary code.

Comment: We don't really have to pay for it since to remove ads, we have adblock, and for the source code, we just copy it. Unless out of the goodness of our hearts, we truly appreciate the community that Bootply is creating.